# Change color of tabletools buttons in DT library in R

Tags: r, datatables, dt

Instead of grey change to a custom color

For example this:

```
library(DT)
iris2 = head(iris, 20)
# only show the Copy and Print buttons
datatable(
  iris2,
  extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = c('copy', 'print')
  )
)
```

Gives us the following:

[image]

What i would like is to change the color of the  buttons Copy and Print.

I have gone through https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/
but i am not able to find a solution.

Comment: I have not programmed in R but you can change the color of the buttons using css rules. for example https://jsfiddle.net/jevtw2g4/12/

Comment: Unfortunately my knowledge in css is limited. I wouldn't know how to "translate" this to R code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can include some javascript/jquery to change the colors of the buttons in the callback:

```
datatable(
        iris2,
        callback=JS('$("button.buttons-copy").css("background","red"); 
                    $("button.buttons-print").css("background","green"); 
                    return table;'),
        extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
                dom = 'Bfrtip',
                buttons = c('copy', 'print')
        )
)
```

Comment: This is great thanks. just as a side question so i understand better this callback logic, how would i go about implementing this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_buttons_animate1

Comment: Are you using this in shiny or a markdown doc? if it is the case it's probably easier to include all the css in your link in a stylesheet.

Comment: For those running recent versions of the packages, I believe the JS has changed slightly and the target is now `button.buttons-copy` and `button.buttons-print`.